# Limit category depth to parent level

Tags: wordpress, parent, categories

There's a couple of problems I need solved here.

1) I can't seem to get this to only list the parent categories.

2) Is there a way I can also show the number of trashed posts next to where I echo $live_posts

```
<ul>
<?php
    $categories = get_categories();
    foreach ($categories as $cat) {     
    $posts = new WP_Query( array(

    'depth'  => 1,
    'post_status' => array('publish'), 
    'cat' => $cat->cat_ID));

    $live_posts = $posts->post_count;
?>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?> (<?php echo $live_posts; ?>)</a>
    </li>
<?php }
?>
</ul>
```

Regarding the first problem, I thought 'depth' => 1 was supposed to limit to the parents, but for reasons unknown it's not working. Unless I'm missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'parent' => 0,
    'hide_empty' => false,
);
$the_query = new WP_Term_Query($args);
$categories = $the_query->get_terms();
print_r($the_query);
exit;
```

Comment: Please explain it